# is there a simple way to convert maven 1 to maven 3

Tags: maven-3, eclipse-juno

I'm using Eclipse Juno 4.2 and the maven Embedded is 3.0.4. I'm not an expert in maven and try to get things by with Stackoverflow help. I've been using maven with eclipse since maven 1 i guess and now have to convert it to maven 3 inorder to make it work. I've used maven-one-plugin to try convert. I ran 'mvn one:converter' and am getting this error...

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to      Central (http://repo1.maven.org/): No connector available to access repository Central  (http://repo1.maven.org/) of type  using the available factories  WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to Central (http://repo1.maven.org/): No connector available to access repository Central (http://repo1.maven.org/) of type  using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.917s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 07 18:51:30 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'one' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/Dev/.m2/repository), Central (http://repo1.maven.org/), ibiblio.org (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I think the main problem is 'No connector is available' part of the WARNING that is causing all this. I have tried to build with mvn:install on Eclipse Juno and am getting similar error for 'No Connector available' as follows...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project Belfast: Unable to generate classpath: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:jar:2.10: Failed to retrieve POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:jar:2.10: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:pom:2.10 from/to Central (http://repo1.maven.org/): No connector available to access repository Central (http://repo1.maven.org/) of type  using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:jar:2.10
```

What exactly am i missing? Are some connectors required by Maven 3 that i dont have on POM? 
MY POM is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MYProj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MYProj</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includesList>com.mysite</includesList>
                <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.2</version>
            <configuration></configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceExcludes> **/.svn/** </warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>[1.3.3,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
        <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mortennobel</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-image-scaling</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
        <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i added Sean's answer to my POM.xml in the following link and build is working now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389744/is-there-a-way-to-tell-surefire-to-skip-tests-in-a-certain-package . However, converting the maven project to maven 3 is still outstanding...

Comment: Have you tested the build on command line mvn clean package? Access to maven central may be via a proxy? If yes you need to configure that in settings.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't tested via command line. There is no proxy that blocks the maven. mvn clean package, from eclipse gui, usually removes all hibernate mapping files from the target. So i rarely use it. In this case, as i have noted above, the build problem is solved. I am looking for maven 1 to maven 3 conversion of pom.xml and other setting files.