# Disable whole test (and loading context) based on Spring Property

Tags: spring, testing

I'm trying to apply TDD in my workflow when I'm working on Spring 5 (not Spring Boot) application, but my running tests take about 45s, which makes my development cycle quite slow. Standard unit tests are super quick, but I have one test which validates Spring context configuration - it takes over 30s on its own.

My idea is to disable this particular test every time during the development cycle and run it just from time to time - e.g. when I create a Docker image with my application/make a commit/push with changes.

So here is what I come up with so far:

1. Define property when docker-profile is run:

   ```
   <profiles>
     <profile>
       <id>docker-build</id>
       <properties>
           <build.profile.id>docker-build</build.profile.id>
       </properties>
       <build>...</build>
     </profile>
   </profiles>
   ```
2. Use it in `test.properties`:

   ```
   app.profile=${build.profile.id}
   ```
3. Use `@EnabledIf` annotation in test:

   ```
    @TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
    @SpringJUnitConfig( classes = MainConfiguration.class )
    @EnabledIf("#{'${app.profile}' == 'docker-build'}")
    public class SpringConfigTest {
      ...
    }
   ```

And it doesn't seem to work - I can be wrong, but `app.profile` property doesn't seem to be available when I call it in `@EnabledIf`. **Or maybe I took a wrong route and there is simpler way to disable this particular test** - I run it as `mvn test` at the moment. I would like to know why `app.profile` property isn't visible for `@EnabledIf` though.

**Edit**
I've discovered I can skip the first two steps and define property in command line:

```
mvn -Dapp.profile=docker-build test
```

But not sure why I can't get property from `test.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to load the context in this case for the spring version of @EnabledIf to eval the expression.  So it would be:

```
@EnabledIf(expression = "#{'${app.profile}' == 'docker-build'}", loadContext = true)
```

Also make sure the property file is included in maven testResources with filtering enabled:

```
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
```

I think above should resolve the specific property issue you are facing.  But since this does not skip loading the spring context perhaps a better way is to configure in the maven profile to skip test based on package or test class name - similar to [Is there a way to tell surefire to skip tests in a certain package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389744/is-there-a-way-to-tell-surefire-to-skip-tests-in-a-certain-package)