# Fail fast in junit testing?

Tags: eclipse, junit, integration-testing, junit4

Is there anyway i can stop the junit eclipse test runner when it fails a test for the first time ?

I prefer to check and fix the failed test before continue testing the rests.

From [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923857/is-there-a-way-to-fail-fast-for-junit-with-the-maven-surefire-plugin), i can see that we can register a listener as a workaround. But i wonder how to register a listener for the eclipse junit runner ?

Comment: Looks like a feature request for the eclipse runner.

Comment: You can still stop it manually if you want to edit the test first.